# Is there any three valued logic with this truth tables?

Tags: logic

```
T AND T = T
T AND U = T
T AND F = F
F AND T = F
F AND U = F
F AND F = F
U AND T = T 
U AND U = U 
U AND F = F

T OR T = T
T OR U = T
T OR F = T
F OR T = T
F OR U = F
F OR F = F
U OR T = T 
U OR U = U 
U OR F = F

NOT T = F
NOT U = U
NOT F = T

T => T = T
F => F = U
T => F = F
F => T = U
```

Add the remaining for implication:

```
U => U = U
T => U = U
F => U = U
U => T = U
U => F = U
```

I'm not very sure about the last two. But if I miss them before I guess it is because they don't add "knowledge".

The idea of U is to meant NOTHING or VOID a thing that doesn't provide any knowledge and from where we cannot obtain any information.

What is the worst paradox this logic could generate?

Edit just to add another concrete interpretation I have when deriving the truth tables. Imaging an expression that runs forever. This espression is VOID because I'm not able to evaluate its truthness.

But probably this is total garbage. Maybe I'm just mixing inconsistents intuitions in my head. If this thing doesn't have a name I have little expectations...

Edit: After some time, my current me thinks the ultimate reason of the question is I don't like LEM standard intepretation. To divide the world in true and false and nothing else. 
Giving formal system limited powers to figure out thruth I find LEM inapropiate as an axiom.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Could you please clarify?

Comment: Is there a name for this logic? A Wikipedia link etc... On three valued logic I saw Kleene logic but I dislike theirs truth tables...

Comment: A beautiful question.

Comment: Is your objection to Kleene the fact that False OR Undef. = Undef.?

Comment: You haven't fully explained how implication is handled - what if a "U" is involved somewhere?

Comment: True AND Undef = Undef I don't like too.

Comment: Incidentally I don't really see how to justify "U or U = U" and "U or F = F" simultaneously. If the idea is that U is something we don't yet know, then "U or F" should equal U. But if the idea is that we remove clauses involving U, then "U or U" becomes the empty disjunction which arguably should equal F (since there is no clause of the empty disjunction which is assigned "true") - and similarly, under this idea we should have "U and U" = T (every clause in the empty conjunction is true).

Comment: @Eduard Why don't you like T and U = U? (I think you should say a bit more about how precisely you envision U behaving, intuitively.)

Comment: U means VOID. VOID doesn't provide you any thruthness of falseness to you who are evaluating the expression. U or F means F because U has NOTHING for you.

Comment: @Eduard But under that interpretation we should have "U or U" be F, and "U and U" be T, for the reasons stated above. And again, you haven't finished the table for implication ...

Comment: Under my totally subjective interpretation when I try to understand an expression that says "VOID or VOID" for me is "VOID"

Comment: I guess I just don't understand your intuition for U. Why should "U implies U" and "U implies T" evaluate to U? I certainly don't see any justification for the latter, unless we're thinking of U as something like "possibly true, possibly false," at which point we (again) throw rules like "T and U is T" into question.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: The AND/OR/NOT rules look like they're motivated by an intuition where $U$ says "imagine this part of the formula was not here at all".

Comment: @HenningMakholm "The AND/OR/NOT rules look like they're motivated by an intuition where  says "imagine this part of the formula was not here at all"." Yes, but then I don't see how to justify for example "U implies T is U." (Your last sentence, though, overstates the situation in my opinion: a classically-correct $\forall x(p(x)\rightarrow q(x))$ would here be interpreted as an infinite conjunction of Ts and Us, which - as long as there's a single T - would evaluate to T here. Of course the issue is what happens if no $x$ satisfies $p$ ...)

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Neither did I at first, but actually it does seem to make sense if we consider that $\to$ makes most sense in the context $\forall x(p(x)\to q(x))$. In that case $p(x)\to q(x)$ becomes $U$ when $x$ doesn't satisfy $p$, and therefore presumably drops out of the interpretation of $\forall$, so we actually get the right truth value at the end -- except that vacuous truths are no longer true but "void". [Note: some crosstalk happend here because I only realized this after posting my first comment, and hastily removed a part that said the opposite of this].

Comment: @HenningMakholm It still does cause a serious problem, though. Consider e.g. "For all $x$, if $x$ is a counterexample to Fermat's last theorem then the Frey curve corresponding to $x$ is non-modular" - that would evaluate to "U" here, even though it really, really shouldn't. It is "vacuous at the bottom" but for highly nontrivial reasons (incidentally, this subjective-but-important distinction between vacuous truths is one reason I support the material implication).

Comment: @NoahSchweber: I'm not saying this is a good idea, only that I can see some kind of motivation for attempting it -- in the hope that it _would_ do what we need and still avoid the conceptual problems many learners have with material implication.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Yes. That's the driver.

Comment: @Eduard In that case - again - how do you justify "$U\implies T$ is $U$"?

Comment: @Noah: agreed that the last two implications  U implies T is U and U implies F is U are not crystal clear. At some time I write it down as T and F respectively, but then I change my mind. Again the original question was if this "logic" has a name or a wiki link from which I can learn more...

Comment: how do you justify "
U⟹T is U"
"? Again not sure at all, but what I think is because I cannot evaluate the first expression (it is still running forever) I obtain no knowledge. So the implication is VOID.

Comment: Not sure if it'll bug you ,but you've lost distributivity:
T AND (F OR U) $\neq$ (T AND F) OR (T AND U)

Comment: I think I see AND, OR and NOT in a diferent level than IMPLIES when evaluating EXPRESSIONS looking for its "truesness".

Comment: @Ali: Yes. A little bit. I need to think a little bit about that. I think an usual proving strategy could be restricting to EXPRESSIONs that make sense (ie true or false) doing standard logic and study the U case separately.

Answer (score -1):

Logically speaking, we should have an equivalence between 
$$P \implies Q $$
and
$$not  Q \implies not  P$$
but in your three valued one,

$$T \implies T ( =T)$$ is not equivalent to
$$F \implies F  (=U)$$

Comment: This question is very imprecise - but whatever the question means, I don't think this is an answer to it!

Comment: @AlexKruckman I agree that the last line is a nonsequitur, but the part about the contrapositive does address the OP's final question "What is the worst paradox this logic could generate?".

Comment: If you change the semantics, there's no reason you "should have" any particular logical equivalence. You could reframe your answer as "one equivalence this semantics doesn't validate is ..." but even then, so? Why is this particular equivalence important? This equivalence doesn't even hold for constructive logic. There are many other classical and constructive equivalences that aren't validated by this semantics, e.g. $\top\land\varphi\equiv\varphi$.